# lock rotation some views swift

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, orientation

I made some of my views landscape and some others portrait.
My problem is that I don't want to allow them to rotate.
If a page is landscape stay just landscape and also for portrait ones.
I searched for it a lot and I tried:

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

and

```
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait
}
```

But it didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just get the orientation with overriding :

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape && flag{
        let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait.rawValue
        UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
        print("Landscape")
    } else if UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait && !flag {
        let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeLeft.rawValue
        UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
        print("Portrait")
    }
}
```

and do somthing like this .

this function won't lock your screen but it'll keep the screen at orientation you want.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track, but when a user is in portrait modus, and you want to force the user in landscape because your view is in landscape, you must change the `UIDevice` orientation.

```
UIDevice.current.setValue(UIDeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
```

For more UIDevice options, see apple documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uideviceorientation

To ensure the user cannot get back to portrait, you add: (the code you already had)

```
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.landscape
}
```

Comment: yes, this make a view landscape or portrait but it still can rotate.

Comment: Are you sure you are overriding `supportedInterfaceOrientations` in the correct ViewController?

Answer (score 1):

Adding this property and function in **AppDelegate**

```
    internal var shouldRotate = false
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
       return shouldRotate ? .landscape : .portrait
    }
```

And where ever you want call this lines

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
appDelegate.shouldRotate = true
```